# Display discount in money and percentage for each variants of a product

Tags: shopify

I have an issue In Debut Theme, I would like to display the amount of money saved and percentage of discount for each variant of a product.

I have this script in product-template.liquid :

```
{% assign amount_saved = current_variant.compare_at_price | minus:current_variant.price | money %}
<p>You saved {{ amount_saved | money }}</p>

<p>-{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price | minus: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price | money_without_currency | replace: ',', '.' | times: 100 | remove: '.0'}}%</p>
```

This works fine for the first variant by default! But how can I make it work with other variants? When I select the other variant, the "amount_saved" seems not to update properly.

Comment: You need to use javascript for achieve that. Try [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) jquery method for trigger the select and update the amount

Answer (score 0):

This is for Cart but maybe you can change to fit product although the code used are wellknown github share.

Comment: {% assign savings = 0 %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.variant.compare_at_price > item.variant.price %}
    {% assign difference = item.variant.compare_at_price | minus: item.variant.price %}
    {% assign savings = savings | plus: difference %}
{% assign actualSaving = savings | times: item.quantity %} 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if savings > 0 %}
  <p><span style="color: #339966; font-size: medium;">(You SAVE : {{ actualSaving | money }})</span></p>
{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

Calculate discount in percentage:

{% for variant in product.variants %}

Save {{ variant.compare_at_price | minus: variant.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: variant.compare_at_price | round }}%

{% endfor %}

Answer (score -1):

To show percentage saved with each variant, you can use this Shopify app: https://apps.shopify.com/discount-saved